# Removing the "Getting Started" webpart with REST API

Tags: web-part, rest, api, delete, homepage

Is there any way to delete the 'Getting started..' webpart from a workspace (actually the home.aspx) via REST API (or POST request)?

Unfortunaly it is not possible to disable the module on the parent site.

The closest I could get was:

```
SHAREPOINT.com/WORKSPACE/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(\'/WORKSPACE/SitePages/Home.aspx\')/GetLimitedWebPartManager(scope=1)/WebParts?$expand=WebPart&$filter=WebPart/Title+eq+\'Get started with your site\'
```

This returns something but it seems that it is not supporting the "DELETE" parameter.

SP2013 (no Powershell access)